# Tensorflow Incompatible shapes: [16,48] vs. [0]

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, siamese-network

I have the following code portion for a siamese network

```
def build_sequential_model(input_shape, embedding_dim=16):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Input(shape=(input_shape,)))
    model.add(Dense(embedding_dim, activation='tanh'))    
    return model


sample_a = Input(shape=ftrSize)
    sample_b = Input(shape=ftrSize)

    feature_extractor = build_sequential_model(ftrSize, embedding_dim=embDim)

    feats_a = feature_extractor(sample_a)
    feats_b = feature_extractor(sample_b)
    # feature_extractor.summary()
    distance = Lambda(utils.euclidean_distance)([feats_a, feats_b])
    outputs = Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(distance)
    model = Model(inputs=[sample_a, sample_b], outputs=outputs)
    model.compile(loss=utils.contrastive_loss, optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.0007),
                  metrics=["accuracy"])  # optimizer="adam", optimizer=Adam(lr=0.001)

    checkpoint_path = 'siamese/1D/db' + str(dBthresh) + '_' + 'emb' + str(embDim) + '_' + excludeName + '.ckpt'

    checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(checkpoint_path, monitor='val_loss', save_best_only=True, mode='min',
                                 save_weights_only=True,
                                 verbose=1,
                                 )
    callback_list = [checkpoint]#, early_stop, reduce_lr]

    history = model.fit(
        [pairs_train[:, 0], pairs_train[:, 1]], labels_train[:],
        validation_data=([pairs_val[:, 0], pairs_val[:, 1]], labels_val[:]),
        batch_size=16,
        epochs=20,
        callbacks=callback_list,
        # verbose=0,
        )
```

where `ftrSize = 56` and `embDim = 48`

I have a loop at I try and test 10 times the same architecture on different sets of my data. At random times I get an error saying:

```
Incompatible shapes: [16,48] vs. [0]
     [[{{node model/lambda/sub}}]] [Op:__inference_test_function_182379]
```

pointing the `sum_squared` line in the euclidean distance function I am using as a Lambda layer

```
def euclidean_distance(vectors):
    feats_a, feats_b = vectors
    sum_squared = K.sum(K.square(feats_a - feats_b), axis=1,
                        keepdims=True)
    return K.sqrt(K.maximum(sum_squared, K.epsilon()))
```

shape [16,48] makes total sense since it's [batch size, embDim] but it seems that the second vector in euclidean_distance is of shape [0]

Upon checking on my test and train pair sets when this error occurs I cannot find erroneous or missing values. Data are numpy arrays

What that shape [0] could possibly mean?
What else could be causing this error?

In similar questions usually the cause is a reshaping or inconsistent input image shapes but this is not in my case

I am using
`Python 3.11.4`
`tensorflow-macos==2.14.0`
`numpy==1.25.2`

Comment: It indicates a shape mismatch of the Lambda layer. The shape [16, 48] means that the feats_a tensor is of shape [16, 48]. But, the second tensor, feats_b, is of shape [0], and causing the incompatible shape error. Try printing the tensor shapes in euclidean_distance function.

Comment: @ShrirangMahajan Thanks for your comment. I actually don't get what tensor of shape [0] is or how it could appear in my data since I know my data is clean... I added  a print(feats_a.shape, feats_b.shape) statement in euclidean_distance function. It prints out during model compile and beginning of training. Surprisingly the error didn't show up in two cases where it would eventually occur at some point of the execution. 
It is strange because in some cases in prints (16, 48) (16, 48) and others (None, 48) (None, 48)